# I need to know if it is possible to create a SSRS report as defined

Tags: ssrs-2008, reporting-services

I have a query with 3 parameters that a user should be able to define:

**AND (ORION_SCHED.TRIP.DATE_TIME = '09/11/2012')

AND (ORION.CUST.COUNTRY = 'BE')

AND (ORION_SCHED.TRIP.ID_SHIFT ='1')**

- DATE_TIME should be a datepicker
- COUNTRY dropdown with defined values
- ID_SHIFT dropdown with defined values

I guess this isn't an issue?

The result of this query will return the dataset

[image]

My actual question: I want the result to be presented in this way

[image]

So always 3 blocks of data next to each other, the data of every block is the result of the query filtered down on the column TRUCK_ID (a sub-select of the returned dataset)

The empty cells per block are a nice to have, these are non-unique values per TRUCK_ID that I don't wish to be repeated on every line, but like I said a nice to have.

Comment: I would add a new column to the query that returned 1,2 or 3 (for each different TRUCK_ID. Then I would use 3 Tablix (one per column on your report) and filter the data by the new column you added on the query. Then you just group on the TruckID on each tablix and play around with the format. It should work.

Comment: Joao's approach sounds good. (@joao, you should move that to an answer.) Sylvio, What have you tried? Where are you getting stuck? You should start building the report and see how far you get. There is no actual question in your question.

Comment: Jamie, Joao`s idea set me on the right path, I managed to create my report based on his input. @joao: Jamie is right, move your approach to an answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would add a new column to the query that returned 1,2 or 3 (for each different TRUCK_ID. Then I would use 3 Tablix (one per column on your report) and filter the data by the new column you added on the query.

Then you just group on the TruckID on each tablix and play around with the format. It should work.